# Getting NullPointerException when using findViewById on a recyclerView in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Trying to build an app with 5 fragments. The first one contains the recyclerView, whenever I switch tabs the Views get discarded and every time I come back when the inflator is inflating the view, at the same time the app tries to get the id of the recyclerView which returns a null pointer exception. And this problem is only getting more complicated, I don't think in using the correct way to do this as I am getting errors will context as well.

If you have any simple examples of apps with fragments having recyclerViews please drop the link below, thank you in advance

**MainActivity.java**

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private FragmentHome fragmentHome = new FragmentHome(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fragmentHome.initGetData();
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavBar);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragmentHome).commit();
    fragmentHome.initRecyclerView();
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        }
    });

}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home: {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragmentHome).commit();
                fragmentHome.initRecyclerView();
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
}
```

**FragmentHome.java**

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {

private String BASE_URL = "https://www.reddit.com";

// INIT RETROFIT AND CALL ONCE AND FOR ALL
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

RedditAPI redditAPI = retrofit.create(RedditAPI.class);


private static final String TAG = "FragmentHome";
private RecyclerView feedRecyclerView;
private List<ChildrenData> childrenData;
private String after;
private String previousAfter = "";
private Boolean isScrolling = false;
private int currentItems;
private int totalItems;
private int scrolledOutItems;
private Context context;
private View inflatingView;


public FragmentHome() {
}

public FragmentHome(Context context) {
    this.context = context; //I also get some attribute warning 
                               here not important right now though.
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflatingView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    initRecyclerView();
    return inflatingView;
}


public void initGetData() {
    Call<FeedData> feedDataCall = redditAPI.getFeed();
    feedDataCall.enqueue(new Callback<FeedData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FeedData> call, final Response<FeedData> response) {
         /*   Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().getData().getChildren().get(0).getDataModel().getTitle());
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().getData().getChildren());*/
            childrenData = response.body().getData().getChildren();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse:  " + childrenData);
            after = response.body().getData().getAfter();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + after);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FeedData> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

public void initRecyclerView() {

    feedRecyclerView = inflatingView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    final FeedRecyclerViewAdapter feedRecyclerViewAdapter = new FeedRecyclerViewAdapter(childrenData, context);
    feedRecyclerView.setAdapter(feedRecyclerViewAdapter);
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    feedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    feedRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            isScrolling = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            currentItems = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItems = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            scrolledOutItems = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (isScrolling && (totalItems - 1 == currentItems + scrolledOutItems) && (!previousAfter.equals(after))) {
                isScrolling = false;
                fetchNewData(after, feedRecyclerViewAdapter);
            }
        }
    });

    }


public void fetchNewData(final String after_use, final FeedRecyclerViewAdapter feedRecyclerViewAdapter) {
    Call<FeedData> feedDataCall_withAfter = redditAPI.getFeed_withAfter(after_use);
    previousAfter = after_use;
    feedDataCall_withAfter.clone().enqueue(new Callback<FeedData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FeedData> call, Response<FeedData> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().toString());
            childrenData.addAll(response.body().getData().getChildren());
            after = response.body().getData().getAfter();
            feedRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FeedData> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    Log.d(TAG, "fetchNewData: " + childrenData.size());
}
}
```

**Error I am getting**
I am getting the following error:

2019-04-15 13:00:28.449 18359-18359/com.example.recyclerview2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.recyclerview2, PID: 18359

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.recyclerview2/com.example.recyclerview2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int) on a null object reference

**StackTrace**
2019-04-15 13:57:00.234 5508-5508/com.example.recyclerview2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclerview2, PID: 5508
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.recyclerview2/com.example.recyclerview2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.recyclerview2.Fragments.FragmentHome.initRecyclerView(FragmentHome.java:92)
        at com.example.recyclerview2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)

Sorry, first post on stack, I don't know how to format code correctly.

Comment: post your error log

Comment: Added in the post edit.

Comment: According to error, Issue is in your adapter. add you adapter code too

Comment: problem lies on FeedRecyclerViewAdapter; in this class, when u tried to get the list size (YOUR_LIST_MODEL.size()), You list remains null. To ignore this, check Your list is null or not before calling size()

Comment: Okay I'm sorry, I think I added the wrong stackTrace, the Adapter is fine, it was working before I introduced the fragments

Comment: Updated the post with the correct stackTrace, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your code is that you are calling `fragmentHome.initRecyclerView();` in `onCreate()` method in **MainActivity**. Fragment view at that point is not created yet. That's why you get **NullPointerException** Remove this line from MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is problem in below line of `initRecyclerView`

```
feedRecyclerView = inflatingView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
```

While the line is executing it seems `inflatingView` is null. But I can't understand why. Please try moving the above line inside `onCreateView()`. Hope this might solve the problem.